# When does a product of two symmetric matrices commute?

Tags: symmetric-matrices

I have two $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

I know that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$. But it does not mean $AB=BA$.
I wonder what is the condition for $AB=BA$.

Comment: The condition for $AB=BA$ is... $AB=BA$. Irony aside, I mean that there is not a general characterization, according to my knowledge, at least.

Comment: Symmetric matrices (presumably real) are diagonalizable. They are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if they commute. But, this fact is not really useful for detecting $AB=BA$. It is very useful for many other purposes though.

Comment: Jyrki: What about the identity and any symmetric matrix that is not diagonal? These commute, but are not simultaneously diagonalizable. I don't think that condition is if and only if.

Comment: @kholli They are certainly simultaneously diagonalizable! The identity matrix is diagonalized by any change of a basis, so we only need to worry about the other matrix :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, yes, being silly. Good point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices

I saw this article, but I can get neither head nor tail of it, as I know whatever is there in the pdf in this link: 1) https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh103.pdf 2) https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh104.pdf but it might be of help to y'all.